# Android R.layout.main not getting resolved

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to android and making my first application.

I have a problem resolving `R.layout.main`

The main is auto generated in my res/layout.

I have already imported `android.R`

but it is still not resolving "main"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are creating a new application for android in eclipse, then **R.java file is auto generated** in your application's `/gen` directory, And your `R.layout.main` is resolved automatically, **For that you don't have to import any R file in your activity class**..

Just remove android.R any any other R file import statements, Clean and rebuild your project it works fine..

Also make sure Your project doesn't have a any error, If its present then it s prevent to generate `R.java` file in `/gen` directory..

Answer (score 2):

Instead of android.R you must import the your package name.R...

Answer (score 1):

Have you imported "your-package".R?

You can find it in "gen" directory.
If R.java is not auto generated, probably there is compile time error, check your ide's messages.

By the way, you define "your-package" in your AndroidManifest file.

Comment: my package name in AndroidManifest file is com.First.calculator, however import com.First.Calculator.R is NOT doing anything. Instead now the error is on "R"

Answer (score 1):

Quick solution:

Remove android.R and just import your package.R file by doing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>

More info:

> Note: Eclipse sometimes likes to add an "import android.R" statement
>   at the top of your files that use resources, especially when you ask
>   eclipse to sort or otherwise manage imports. This will cause your make
>   to break. Look out for these erroneous import statements and delete
>   them.

Look at your imports. There is android.R imported, remove it, so that your project will resolve R not with the default Android Resources class, but with the one auto-generated from your /res/ folder.

Answer (score 1):

R.java file should be auto generated, but I could not find it. So I just deleted my project and created it again and this time everything went fine - I've got R.java and the error resolving R disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Problem: Not resolving R.layout.main

Solution: In your Activity Java class import as following

> > import [Package Name].R

Example >> import com.example.tutorial.R